# How do I make something stay highlighted in ag-charts?

Tags: ag-charts, ag-charts-react

I'm trying to figure out how to make something (e.g. a single bar) in ag-charts stay highlighted/selected after a click.

After looking through the documentation, it doesn't seem to be any functionality to achieve this.

Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the nodeClick event.

There is an example showing this in the documentation at https://charts.ag-grid.com/javascript/events/#example-toggling-nodes-selected-state.